# Access a shared folder over the network

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares, user-accounts

I'm on Windows 7, I created some user accounts with passwords, created some folders, shared every folder with the exact user I want to grant access to.

Now, I want a given user to access his folder with his username/password, from another computer on the network.

NB: when I type the IP of the host computer I can access the Public folder, but I can't find where to put the user/pass to get the shared folder for that login.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Explorer, put in the address bar the name of one of the shared folders:
`\\hostname\Shared-Folder-3\`
This is different from just clicking the visible folders. Truly, though, if the folder is not visible, then you might be using Home Groups which affect permissions.

If you are comfortable using the command line interface, we will try using `net use`.

```
net use w: \\othercomputer\Shared-Folder-3\ /user:othercomputer\username
```

That should prompt for a password. Now, it takes several tries to get this right. If at any point it says you cannot connect as a different user because it's already connected, do a `net use /delete *` to remove all credentialed connections. Or a `net use /delete \\othercomputer\Shared-Folder-2\`

To see what is currently connected, run

```
net use
```

Comment: it says you dont have the permission and doesn't give the option to login

Comment: try using IP address of the machine instead of name and give the password.

Comment: from the beginning I'm using the IP